# MYSQL Part of my WHERE Query isn't been run

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have a mysqlqeury that is being used in a search function, i'm trying retrieve all data from the database that matches the keywords if the startdate is equal to or lower than todays date and the end date is equal to or greater than todays date.

The query works great if i'm not checking for the keywords but when i am checking for keywords the start date and end date don't match my WHERE Statement.

This part of the query isn't been run:

```
AND ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00'))
```

If i remove this part from my query all the result stay the same.

For instance i get values with Startdates like: 2015-12-23
And Enddates like: 2015-09-20

My Full query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_date, p.post_status, p.post_type, p.post_content, p.post_excerpt, ad.date_start, ad.date_end  FROM wp_posts as p join wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID JOIN agenda_meta as am ON p.ID = am.post_id JOIN agenda_dates as ad ON p.ID = ad.post_id WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'  AND ( p.post_type = 'tentoonstellingsagenda' ) AND ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00')) AND ( p.post_title LIKE '%sprookje%' ) OR p.post_content LIKE '%sprookje%' OR (pm.meta_key='_ap_place_city' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sprookje%')  AND ( am.land = 1 ) GROUP BY p.ID  ORDER BY IF (ad.date_start = DATE('2015-12-05') , 1, IF (ad.date_start <= DATE('2015-12-05') , 2, 3 )) DESC, ad.date_start DESC
```

When running my query in PHPMYADMIN i get no error's whatsover, so not really understanding where this is going wrong...:(

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

I also tried changing the part of the query that isn't working to:

```
 AND ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' ) AND ( ad.date_end >= '2015-12-05' )
```

This gave me the same results..

Also tried only to check for start date and still not getting any diffrent results:

```
 AND ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' )
```

Comment: Your error is in the `OR` clause(s) and your lack of brackets to enclose each requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find that formatting a query with each contition on a new line helps to see what is going on.  The number of 'open' and 'close' brackets should match on each line, and each line is 1 requirement.

Your query is:

```
WHERE       p.post_status = 'publish'  
    AND     ( p.post_type = 'tentoonstellingsagenda' ) 
    AND     ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00')) 
    AND     ( p.post_title LIKE '%sprookje%' ) 
    OR      p.post_content LIKE '%sprookje%' 
    OR      (pm.meta_key='_ap_place_city' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sprookje%')
```

Your records do not have to match any of your clauses before the `OR`, if they match the `OR`.  I think that you need this:

```
WHERE       p.post_status = 'publish'  
    AND     ( p.post_type = 'tentoonstellingsagenda' ) 
    AND     ( ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00')) 
    AND     (( p.post_title LIKE '%sprookje%' ) OR p.post_content LIKE '%sprookje%' OR  (pm.meta_key='_ap_place_city' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sprookje%'))
```

All I have done is added brackets around your last 3 requirements so that they are evaluated as 1 requirement (not an alternative requirement).

Comment: You my friend are my HERO of the day :P Thanks for the help this was indeed the problem, So dumb that i didn't think of this :P

Answer (score 1):

i think it's because you don't group the search condition into one group so there is OR in the main condition.

```
// ..........
WHERE
p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (p.post_type = 'tentoonstellingsagenda') 
AND (ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' 
     AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00')) 
AND (p.post_title LIKE '%sprookje%') 
OR p.post_content LIKE '%sprookje%' 
OR (pm.meta_key = '_ap_place_city' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sprookje%')
AND (am.land = 1)
```

because the OR in the xxx LIKE '%%' is on the main WHERE condition so when there is one OR condition is meet then it is true (other will be ignored).

try changing it into:

```
WHERE
p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_type = 'tentoonstellingsagenda'
AND (ad.date_start <= '2015-12-05' 
     AND ('2015-12-05' <= ad.date_end || ad.date_end = '0000-00-00')) 
AND ((p.post_title LIKE '%sprookje%') 
     OR (p.post_content LIKE '%sprookje%')
     OR (pm.meta_key = '_ap_place_city' and pm.meta_value LIKE '%sprookje%'))
AND am.land = 1
```